# How do I change the built-in button labels on a gtk.Assistant?

Tags: python, pygtk, wizard

I want to change the label of the 'Apply' button of a `gtk.Assistant` to 'Start'.  I can't find the corresponding `gtk.Button` widget in the `Assistant` instance.

Here's some basic code for a two-page `Assistant`:

```
import gtk

a = gtk.Assistant()

page = gtk.CheckButton("Something optional")
a.append_page(page)
a.set_page_type(page, gtk.ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONTENT)
a.set_page_title(page, "Make decisions")
a.set_page_complete(page, True)

page = gtk.Label("Alright, let's build some foo.")
a.append_page(page)
a.set_page_type(page, gtk.ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONFIRM)
a.set_page_title(page, "Confirm")
a.set_page_complete(page, True)

a.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
a.connect('close', gtk.main_quit)
a.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

On the final page you'll see the 'Apply' button. I want to change that text to 'Start'.

`gtk.Assistant.children()` and `.get_children()` return the list of page widgets.

`gtk.Assistant.get_child()` returns None.

`gtk.Assistant.get_action_area()` isn't a method.

Here's a link to the documentation.: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkassistant.html

How do I find the `gtk.Button` I'm interested in?

Comment: This guy seems to have the same problem as you: http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg14905.html


But he seems to suggest that your desired modification is possible in C. Have you tried something like this in C? If it possible you might be able to do the coding portion for this in C, and then bind the C code to Python and run that small portion of the code there.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the suggestion seems like brutal overkill, but the only way I can think of to get it to work, is to hack the actual implementation itself. This doesn't seem very easy to do it from python...

Comment: @eazar Thanks for the suggestion. It's massively overkill, but without changing PyGTK itself there doesn't seem to be another way.

Comment: @eazar Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I would post the answer, but the only problem is that I haven't tested it out to see if it actually works. I have never actually tried gtk in C before. If I get time later on today, I will give it a shot, and if it works I'll post an answer [=

Comment: I actually managed to [find a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15891203/182642) to cleverly access the widget containing the buttons without getting into C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution while experimenting with workarounds.

`gtk.Assistant` overrides the `gtk.Container.get_children()` method with something that returns the list of pages, but it is still in fact the parent of a `gtk.HBox()` which contains the buttons for 'Next', 'Apply', 'Cancel', etc.

The method `gtk.Assistant.add_action_widget()` adds a widget to the so-called "action area". It turns out this is the `HBox` containing the relevant buttons. The following function will produce a reference to the `HBox`:

```
def get_buttons_hbox(assistant):
    # temporarily add a widget to the action area and get its parent
    label = gtk.Label('')
    assistant.add_action_widget(label)
    hbox = label.get_parent()
    hbox.remove(label)
    return hbox
```

Then the buttons are retrieved using `get_buttons_hbox(a).get_children()`.

```
for child in get_buttons_hbox(a).get_children():
    print child.get_label()
```

This prints:

```
gtk-goto-last
gtk-go-back
gtk-go-forward
gtk-apply
gtk-cancel
gtk-close
```

So the following code solves the problem (using `get_buttons_hbox()` defined above):

```
for child in get_buttons_hbox(a).get_children():
    label = child.get_label()
    if label == 'gtk-apply':
        child.set_label('Start')
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will be possible with pygtk.  If you switch to GObject Introspection with python you can set a fully custom action area.  From the [Gtk3 GtkAssistant](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAssistant.html) documentation:

> If you have a case that doesn't quite fit in GtkAssistants way of
>   handling buttons, you can use the GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CUSTOM page type
>   and handle buttons yourself.

and

> **GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CUSTOM** Used for when other page types are not
>   appropriate. No buttons will be shown, and the application must add
>   its own buttons through gtk_assistant_add_action_widget().

Comment: Unfortunately, GObject Introspection is not yet available on Windows, so I can't use this solution.

Comment: Oh, I see.  eazar001's solution works, but it's unattractive for obvious reasons.  IMHO the proper/pythonic way would be to create your own GtkWindow-based composite widget. GtkAssistant is just a convenience class after all, and not a _terribly_ complex one at that (cf. "Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated" -- Zen of Python)